# Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, store

I am having this error in my console I tried many things but it didn't work out.Here is the code below

```
function configureStore_a() {
  const store: any = configureStore({
    reducer: {},
  });
 
  store.ascReducers = {};

  

  
  return store;
}
```

Comment: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#full-example

Comment: You have no reducers, so I don't know what you are expecting.